# My installer fails to register a DLL with E_ACCESSDENIED, and the DLL has a padlock icon when viewed in Explorer

Tags: windows, inno-setup, uac, regsvr32, dllregistration

I use Inno Setup as my installer. The installer failed to register a DLL. It turned out that regsvr32 failed with error code 0x80070005, which stands for E_ACCESSDENIED. When I opened "C:\Program Files\MyProgram\" in Explorer it showed some sort of a UAC dialog asking for elevated priviledges to view it. I noticed that all the files have a padlock on their icons. This is the first time I've seen this padlock.

[image]

I checked in Process Explorer and the installer was started from the regular user account (with elevated priviledges).

### Update

I want to add that this error has so far only happened once. When I closed the installer and started it again (the same exact executable, I haven't made any changes to it), everything went fine and the files in the program's directory had normal permissions. This is not a consistently reproducible bug, more like a one in a million times bug, but if it's happened once on my machine, it likely has happened on users' mahcines too.

Comment: Check your installation script for commands that change permissions of the files.

Answer (score 1):

As it's reporting you don't have access to that folder (and in turn those files). Check the permissions as this is NOT the default state and must have been explicitly changed.